# Create new columns in pandas DataFrame using List Comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

So I have a `pandas` DataFrame that has several columns that contain values I'd like to use to create new columns using a function I've defined. I'd been planning on doing this using Python's List Comprehension as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/10985196). Here's what I'd been trying:

```
df['NewCol1'], df['NewCol2'] = [myFunction(x=row[0], y=row[1]) for row in zip(df['OldCol1'], df['OldCol2'])]
```

This runs correctly until it comes time to assign the values to the new columns, at which point it fails, I believe because it hasn't been iteratively assigning the values and instead tries to assign a constant value to each column. I feel like I'm close to doing this correctly, but I can't quite figure out the assignment.

EDIT:

The data are all strings, and the function performs a fetching of some different information from another source based on those strings like so:

```
def myFunction(x, y):
    # read file based on value of x
    # search file for values a and b based on value of y
    return(a, b)
```

I know this is a little vague, but the helper function is fairly complicated to explain.

The error received is:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: can you post the sample data and expected output also post the error you are getting

Comment: Can you share the code for `myFunction` ?

Comment: Just edited with info on the function and the error received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()`

```
df['NewCol1'], df['NewCol2'] = zip(*[myFunction(x=row[0], y=row[1]) for row in zip(df['OldCol1'], df['OldCol2'])])
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Can I ask what the asterisk after the outer call to `zip()` is for?

Comment: this will help [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)